# Mac on High Sierra won't shutdown cleanly: black screen with mouse

Tags: shutdown

*Similar to issue "[mac book pro sierra does not shutdown stays idle with a black screen and mouse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264806/mac-book-pro-sierra-does-not-shutdown-stays-idle-with-a-black-screen-and-mouse)".*

Apple logo > Shutdown leads to black screen with mouse cursor. Stays like that for hours.

Realized this problem because it wouldn't install Mojave (also won't install 10.13.6 update). Seems I'm stuck on 10.13.3.

I tried [verbose mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201573), but get the same black screen with no text on shutdown (did see lots of black screen with text on startup).

I get a bit more information when shutting down from Terminal:

```
$ sudo shutdown -r now
...
shutdown: / is busy updating; waiting for lock
```

Stays like that for hours. I used Activity Monitor to kill some random applications (starting with launchd) and it proceeds to shutdown. I narrowed it down to killing kextd to complete shutdown.

I've tried [resetting PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204063).
I've tried [resetting SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201295).
I've tried removing everything from Login items (in Users & Groups).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Restarting in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201262) allowed proper shutdown:

> Start your Mac, then immediately press and hold the Shift
>   key. The Apple logo appears on your display.
>
> Release the Shift key when you see the
>   login window.

I was able to use safe mode used this to update to 10.13.6 (problem still existed) and 10.14 (problem resolved -- can now shutdown).

Answer (score 2):

The same happened to me after upgrading to 10.14.6.

As referring to the answer [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103911), I tried to shutdown with

`sudo shutdown -h now`

then terminal stuck with

`shutdown: / is busy updating; waiting for lock`

then I opened Activity Monitor and just force killed the process named `kextd`

Comment: No good that it's happening again. Looks like you had the same scenario I outlined in the question (shutdown, stuck, kill kextd). Did that permanently fix the problem for you? The problem was recurrent for me until I used safe mode to update.

Comment: Yes it has permanently fixed my problem.